# How to identify "externally visible types" and limit visibility for "CA1724: Type names should not match namespaces"?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, roslyn-code-analysis, software-quality

**TL;DR:** see the last question at the end for a one-liner summary.

I'm working on updating an ASP.NET Core app from .NET 6 to .NET 7 and in the process, two new instances of [CA1724: Type names should not match namespaces](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/quality-rules/ca1724) have popped up:

> Warning CA1724: The type name Pipeline conflicts in whole or in part with the namespace name 'Azure.Core.Pipeline'. Change either name to eliminate the conflict.

> Warning CA1724: The type name Region conflicts in whole or in part with the namespace name 'Microsoft.Identity.Client.Region'. Change either name to eliminate the conflict.

The proposed solution per the documentation is to rename the user-created types (`Pipeline` and `Region`) so there is no longer a conflict, however these are arguably the most reasonable names for these particular classes and must remain public. Instead of renaming these classes arbitrarily to something less ideal solely for the purpose of clearing these warnings, it seems like another solution would be to make changes so the conflicting type names (`Azure.Core.Pipeline` and `Microsoft.Identity.Client.Region`) are no longer externally visible but I'm not sure how to go about doing this since these appear to be references from packages and not references in code.

I ran searches for "Azure" and "Microsoft.Identity" but, as expected, found no references. We are using Microsoft Identity in our web project/presentation layer, however I'm not sure what exactly is causing `Microsoft.Identity.Client.Region` (or something under this namespace) to be externally visible. Additionally, we aren't using Azure at all in our code, so I'm a little surprised to see this referenced. I did come across something recently where a package we're using lists an Azure-related package as a dependency, so I'm wondering if this is where the `Azure.Core.Pipeline` reference is coming from, but even then, why would a dependency package of a NuGet package we're using internally and not (intentionally) exposing publicly be "externally visible"?

Instead of changing the names of our classes, how can I identify why these internal dependencies are flagged as externally visible and make changes so they're visible internally to the code using them but not externally to things that have no business accessing them?

Comment: If you added [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), it would be easier to tell. I'm not sure, at this stage. What's the temple of asp.net core you used?